# Mediatek Linkit One Error when compiling in Arduino IDE 1.6.6: arm-none-eabi-g++: no such file or directory

Tags: arduino-ide

So, as you can see in the title, I am having a problem with my Linkit One. I am using Arduino IDE 1.6.6, and I am using the Linkit One SDK 1.1.17 through the Arduino board's manager. When I compile anything, even a simple bare minimum Arduino program, I get this error:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ~My System Path\Temp\build3694385943597424511.tmp/syscalls_mtk.c.o: No such file or directory Error compiling.
```

I have searched long and hard for an answer to this problem, and I have found nothing. Please inform me if I need to provide extra information.

Thanks, Fiske

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay: Here is what I did. First of all, I switched to IDE 1.6.5, like you said. Then I followed the tutorial here: https://www.hackster.io/seeyouu/smart-city-bus-network-9f4cb0. FINALLY I got the linkit to work. You have no idea how long that took.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by editing platform.txt

and adding  **core/**  so that it reads:

```
{build.path}/core/syscalls_mtk.c.o
```

instead of

```
{build.path}/syscalls_mtk.c.o
```

platform.txt was located in:

/Users/awootton/Library/Arduino15/packages/LinkIt/hardware/arm/1.1.17

Answer (score 0):

Try v1.6.5 of the ide. Seemed to fix the issue for us!